# Can you create folders in Snowflake/Snowsight for dashboards?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are going to sunset one of our BI tools and push some of the dashboard building into Snowsight. However, there is now good way to organize dashboards by team via folders, spaces, content groupings, etc. I know we can do this in worksheets so it seems odd that I cannot do the same for dashboards.

Any thoughts, tips, tricks?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot create folders in the Dashboard section. Instead you may use a certain naming convention and then sort by title.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Feels like they're missing some pretty basic features ATM.